# forcing a column to be primary split column in RandomForest

Tags: classification, h2o

I have data for various institutes such that certain institutes provide us more fields than others. These additional data fields seem to have a high correlation to the binary outcome we are trying to predict, so ignoring them is not an option. Also, we don't want build institute specific models.

One of the options we are considering is including institute value as a feature with that idea that a single model will consider it to be the feature used for splitting primarily. Thus, if we imagine a tree based model, each institute gets it's own tree in a single model.

How could we force a feature to be the primary split feature?

Comment: this doesn't sound like the intended use of random forest. please see http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html#distributed-random-forest-drf for an overview of how random forest works. As for the column selection the parameter that limits how columns are randomly selected is mtries.

Comment: Doesn't have to be specific to RandomForest, but, want to know if I could force a feature to be the primary split feature.

Answer (score 1):

This is not something you can do with H2O's tree-based algorithm, and these algos are not designed for the user to decide which feature to split on - this is something the algorithm figures out for you.

From the H2O-3 user guide:

**How does DRF decide which feature to split on?**
It splits on the column and level that results in the greatest reduction in residual sum of the squares (RSS) in the subtree at that point. It considers all fields available from the algorithm. Note that any use of column sampling and row sampling will cause each decision to not consider all data points, and that this is on purpose to generate more robust trees. To find the best level, the histogram binning process is used to quickly compute the potential MSE of each possible split. The number of bins is controlled via nbins_cats for categoricals, the pair of nbins (the number of bins for the histogram to build, then split at the best point), and nbins_top_level (the minimum number of bins at the root level to use to build the histogram). This number will then be decreased by a factor of two per level.

For nbins_top_level, higher = more precise, but potentially more prone to overfitting. Higher also takes more memory and possibly longer to run.

(same goes for GBM and for randomize trees you can look here: http://docs.h2o.ai/h2o/latest-stable/h2o-docs/data-science/drf.html#extremely-randomized-trees)

Comment: Thanks. I would like the algo to figure out the rest of the splits except for the first one. Are there any algorithms outside of H2O that can allow this?

Comment: You could split your data based on whatever feature and threshold yourself and then train trees for each split. You can then combine the two trees and the root split into the final model.

Comment: @vaclav could you share a Python example of this?

Comment: @add787 I don't have an example readily available, but you can simply split the data by your feature and threshold manually. Then you have two data-frames, let's call them `data_left` and `data_right`. Now you can train a tree on both left and right data and stitch them together into a final tree where the root branches into left and right branch based on the threshold and feature you chose, and then each branch corresponds to the models you obtained for `data_left` and `data_right`.

Comment: @vaclav, that is great, but we use complex models such as xgboost for the remaining portion. How do I add my own tree on the top of the xgboost model?

Comment: @add787 Using if-else in Python. You will need to do it programmatically.

Comment: @vaclav, but that won't allow us to have a single model object deployed to prod. We will have to create at least a couple of models and then run them with if else. That is definitely our fall back option, but, wanted to see if there is a better way.